# How can I get data from user for configuring my selenium bot?

Tags: python, selenium, configuration, user-interaction

I'm working on a *Selenium* bot using *Python*.

#### What I want

When the user runs the python script, a console shows up and asks questions to configure the bot, like:

```
How many posts do you want? (1-10)
How many users do you want? (1-10)
etc.
```

After receiving all the answers from the user, it will say something like:

```
A'ight, we're go for the process!
```

and does its job.

#### Question

How can I do something like this, any ideas?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: if you start cody in console then you could use standard `input()`. if you don't start in console then you may have to build GUI with `tkinter`, `PyQt`, etc. Some of them may have already `dialog box` to ask one thing - and then you have to open next box for next thing.

Comment: [15.8. Tkinter Standard Dialog Boxes](https://runestone.academy/runestone/books/published/thinkcspy/GUIandEventDrivenProgramming/02_standard_dialog_boxes.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start cody in console then you could use standard `input()` and `print().

```
answer1 = input("How many posts do you want? (1-10)")
answer2 = input("How many users do you want? (1-10)")

print("A'ight, we're go for the process!")
```

If you don't start in console then you may have to build GUI with `tkinter`, `PyQt`, etc. All of them should have `dialog boxes` to ask one thing. And then you have to use it many times for many questions.

Based on examples from [15.8. Tkinter Standard Dialog Boxes](https://runestone.academy/runestone/books/published/thinkcspy/GUIandEventDrivenProgramming/02_standard_dialog_boxes.html)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog
from tkinter import messagebox

main_window = tk.Tk()
main_window.root.withdraw()  # hide main window

answer1 = simpledialog.askinteger("Input", "How many posts do you want? (1-10)",
                                  parent=main_window, minvalue=1, maxvalue=10)

answer2 = simpledialog.askinteger("Input", "How many users do you want? (1-10)",
                                  parent=main_window, minvalue=1, maxvalue=10)

messagebox.showinfo("Info", "A'ight, we're go for the process!")

main_window.destroy()
```